# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes)

Tags: php

can anyone help me on this error!
**"Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes)"**
this error occurs when i fetch record from database table of all courses available (total course are 84 in number).
My function is:-

```
function allCouses()
{
    include 'connect.php';
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM master_course WHERE mc_enabled=1 AND mc_deleted=0";
    $data = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($data))
    {
        $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
        while($record)
            $course[]=$record;
        return $course;
    }
}
```

the error occur When i store all the record in `$course[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping on, well the wrong thing, ***and have written an infinite while loop***, and you need the `mysqli_fetch_assoc` inside the while loop to read all the rows in the result set.

```
function allCouses()
{
    include 'connect.php';
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM master_course WHERE mc_enabled=1 AND mc_deleted=0";
    $data = mysqli_query($con, $qry);

    while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data) ) {
        $course[]=$record;
    }
    return $course;
}
```

It would also be a better idea to make your database connection in the main body of the script and then pass `$con` as a parameter to each function that requires it. The process of making a connection is in comparison quite a slow one, so you only want to do it once per script.

```
<?php
function allCouses($con)
{
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM master_course WHERE mc_enabled=1 AND mc_deleted=0";
    $data = mysqli_query($con, $qry);

    while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data) ) {
        $course[]=$record;
    }
    return $course;
}



include 'connect.php';

$courses = allCourses($con);
```